# Problems with Logitech HD Webcam C270

Tags: 12.04, webcam, skype, logitech

I am writing you concerning the webcam mentioned in subject above.
I bought this webcam and tried to make it work with skype on a Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit system.

Unfortunately there is a problem. When using it with skype, even though my conversation partner receives a proper picture of me, the picture of her sometimes doesn't work at all, sometimes I see her, but overlayed/intefered with a lots of blue "shadows" which makes the visual contact nearly impossible.

The problem could have something to do with the visual driver, may be, because when I try the webcam under skype --> Options --> video I receive a proper image of myself. Another thing is that I installed cheese, but there the cam doesn't appear at all, instead the program breaks down always.

I haven't found a solution yet to the problem, which is the reason while I am asking for help.

Comment: How is the picture you *receive* in Skype related to *your* webcam?

Answer (score 0):

If Cheese doesn't work for you, try instead `guvcview` package. You can install it in a terminal emulator using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

But first you need to completely remove `cheese` package with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge cheese
```

and after that reboot your PC and only after that install `guvcview` using the command line I mentioned before.

**Guvcview** is not as gifted as Cheese but it will automatically adjust your webcam for performance instead of quality and you will have to manually adjust brightness, contrast and all that from Guvcview interface if you are not satisfied with them. Cheese bets on quality over performance and this is why some users go with Guvcview because they find Cheese to be too demanding for their specific hardware.

And I think you should also install some video drivers for your graphic card. I believe your main problem is related to the fact that you forgot to upgrade your video drivers to the latest version available in Ubuntu repositories or as an aternative you can try installing video drivers available on the manufacturer's official website. Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu are [on this page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and ATI drivers for Ubuntu can be found [on this page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

Comment: Thank you Floppy for your immediate response.
I tried what you suggested and now my system is up to date (Ubuntu 14.04 and the newest intel graphic driver). I also installed GUVCview and have access to the Logitech Webcam. 
Unfortunatelly there is still the same problem appearing in connection with skype: if I turn out my camera the visuals of my conversation partner is super, but the moment I turn it on I see him behind flickerng blue shadows, even though he sees me trough my camera very good.

Comment: So I think it may has something to do with skype itself. But what esle than the newest version (4.3) can I do then?

Comment: Maybe you should remove skype completely, reboot computer, and install skype again : **sudo apt-get purge skype** and after reboot run **sudo apt-get install skype**. Or you can just delete your skype profile and data from **/home/username/.Skype**. To do this one, open your file manager and press Ctrl+H key combination to be able to see the hidden folders in your home directory. After you delete skype data, you can open skype and run the audio-video wizard again and see what happens next.

Comment: I have also found some other reason why skype image can sometimes look blurry or flicker. It is related to your video card settings, and you need to find a way to access your Intel Graphics control panel settings and choose for IMAGE SETTINGS something like “Let the 3D application decide” or you can look for **anisotropic filtering** and **antialiasing** and make sure they are both set on performante settings (lower settings), and not on quality settings (highest settings).

Comment: Ok thanks again, very much. Unfortunatelly it didn't work with your first suggestion. And regarding your second: in different fora I found the comment that it is very difficult, if not impossible at all, to access settings. Nevertheless I installed guvcview, but didn't changed anything, because I was not sure what to change there. Nothing matched your discribtion and I did't want to scew the pooch. Anyway I gave the Webcam back and Skype via my Smartphone now. Thanks again for your effort. I preciate that a lot.

Comment: Well, let's hope you have better luck with a new webcam.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is swapping from USB3 to USB2 slot.